# Erro SELECT SQL Server VB NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
Using con As SqlConnection = getconnectionSQL()
Try
    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * From Diaria where data='" & 
            data_SQL(TextBox4.Text) & "' and prefixo='" & 
            Trim(TextBox14.Text) & "'", con)

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader '= command.ExecuteReader()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.Read() Then
        con.Close()
        con.Open()  
    end if
```

Ao buscar valores na tabela me aparece o seguinte erro:

> startIndex não pode ser maior que o comprimento da cadeia de caracteres.
>   Nome do parâmetro: startIndex.
>   dbo.Diaria:
>   data  date
>   prefixo  nchar(6)
>   bomba  smallint
>   diesel  numeric(4,1)

***Observação***: esse era um programa feito em VB6, sou iniciante em VB6 e VB.net, estou tentando migrar para .net

Comment: `data` é qual tipo de campo no seu Banco de dados? e `prefixo` qual é o tipo de campo no seu Banco de Dados? (Observação: além de fazer errado está usando uma proposta errada também, esqueça VB 6 e tente focar em VB.Net coisas se assemelham mas, a parte de banco por exemplo é totalmente diferente)

Comment: TABELA
data    date
prefixo  nchar(6)
bomba  smallint
diesel  numeric(4, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente, se está fazendo errado, uma solução exemplo simples é assim:

<sup>***Implicito:***</sup>

---

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim Dados As New DataTable
SQL = "SELECT * From Diaria where data=@data and prefixo=@prefixo"
Using db = New SqlConnection("")
   Using command = New SqlCommand(SQL, db)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", New DateTime())
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prefixo", "texto")
        Dados.Load(command.ExecuteReader())
   End Using
End Using
```

onde Dados é [DataTable](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8) com as informações, mas, isso só foi mesmo para exemplifica. O problema do seu código é por possuir parâmetros onde você estava passando errado e podendo ocasionar problemas de conversão, problemas de segurança e a arquitetura .NET já faz o papel pesado para você com o auxilio dos [Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) como exemplificado nessa resposta, no lugar de `New DateTime()` passe uma variável do tipo com o valor de pesquisa e assim serve para todos os outros [Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8), sempre passe o tipo de dado com o valor referente.

Foi feito um exemplo pequeno mas, que abrangem a troca de um dado não tratado com o do [Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8), evitando muitos problemas principalmente de conversão e tratando um código mais esperado pela arquitetura.
Você também pode especificar o tipo de dado enviado, exemplo:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.Date).Value = New DateTime()
```

isso é um código mais usual:

<sup>***Explicito:***</sup>

---

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim Dados As New DataTable
SQL = "SELECT * From Diaria where data=@data and prefixo=@prefixo"
Using db = New SqlConnection("")
    Using command = New SqlCommand(SQL, db)
        command.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.Date).Value = New DateTime()
        command.Parameters.Add("@prefixo", SqlDbType.NChar, 6).Value = "123456"
        Dados.Load(command.ExecuteReader())
    End Using
End Using
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [SqlConnection Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.8)
- [SqlCommand Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8)
- [DataTable](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8)

<sub>***Exemplos:***</sub>

- [Problemas com parâmetros no SqlCommand](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44685/problemas-com-par%c3%a2metros-no-sqlcommand)
- [Parâmetros do SqlCommand e ExecuteReader](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44886/par%c3%a2metros-do-sqlcommand-e-executereader)
- [Como posso fazer um if se os dados da DataBase for True ou False](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282307/como-posso-fazer-um-if-se-os-dados-da-database-for-true-ou-false)
- [Erro de conversão de tipo ao salvar no banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293843/erro-de-convers%c3%a3o-de-tipo-ao-salvar-no-banco-de-dados)

Comment: Não consigo testar hoje, mas amanhã logo cedo dou feedback sobre a solução, de qualquer forma já agradeço.

Comment: A mesma mensagem de erro continua a aparecer.

Comment: O erro estava em um QUERY  abaixo deste, como a consulta não trazia nenhum valor, a mesma passava direto pelo if e ia para um instrução abaixo a qual apresentava o erro.